# creating a login page but button click doesn't show any data or error messages

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

When i click on the submit button it doesn't show any error and does not respond with any message.after a click it only reload itself and doesn't show any data. please reply me with the error.

**I found I missed the  tag. It was a silly mistake.**

```
<?php
    $server="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="admin007#";
    $dbname="demo";

    $con=new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$dbname); 
    if(!$con)
     {
      die('error connecting to the database');
     }


  if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $a=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
    $b=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$a' AND password='$b'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $check=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($check>0){
       echo "you are logged in";    
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Error";
    }
 }

?>

<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <tr>
         <td>Username:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="user" value=""/></td>
      </tr>
      <br /><br />
      <tr>
         Password:
         <td><input type="password" name="pass" value=""/></td>
      </tr>
      <br />
      <tr align="center">
         <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In"/></td>
      </tr>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your form tag? Form Action? :x
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
Scroll down to "The Submit Button"

Comment: Add form to your page :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `<form>` Tag missing

```
<body>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="user" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <br />
    <br />
    <tr>
      Password:
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="pass" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <br />
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: HOW SILLY I'M SORRY FOR BOTHERING YOU :)

Answer (score 0):

The `<form method="post">` around the input fields is missing. Besides that, the `<table>` is also missing :)

Make the magic happen with something like:

```
<body>
<form method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="user" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
Password:
<td><input type="password" name="pass" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center"><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="login"  value="Log In"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

PS: No `<br>` Tags between `<tr>` Tags - thats semantic nonsense (use CSS instead) ... and modern day HTML developers will go full rage when you use `<table>` tags for layout purposes :)